# Select one radio button in each accordian tab using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to select one radio button in each tab. But when I select one radio button in one tab and then when i move in another tab and checked another radio button then the previous selected radio button was automatically removed though i am calling each tab with different id.

Please see the code:

```
<form id="myForm">
        <section id="tab1" class="tab-content active">
            <div id="collartab1">
            <ul class="style-ul">
            <li>
            <a>
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK). 'media/measurement_images/collar/point.png'; ?>"  alt="sample" />

                <input type="radio" name="collar" id='point' value="Point" >
                <label for="point">
                <span> Point</span>
                </label>
                </a>
                </li>
                <li>
            <a>
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK). 'media/measurement_images/collar/semi-sepread.png'; ?>" alt="sample" />
                <input type="radio" name="collar" id='semi-spread' value="SEMI SPREAD" > 

                <label for="semi-spread"> <span>SEMI SPREAD</span></label> 

                </a>
                </li>
                <li>
            <a>
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK). 'media/measurement_images/collar/spread.png'; ?>"  alt="sample" />

                <input type="radio" name="collar" id='spread' value="SPREAD" >

                <label for="spread"> <span>SPREAD</span></label>

                </a>
                </li>
                <li class="border"></li>
                <li>
            <a>
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK). 'media/measurement_images/collar/button-down.png'; ?>" alt="sample" />
                <input type="radio" name="collar" id='button-down' value="BUTTON DOWN" > 

               <label for="button-down"> <span>BUTTON DOWN</span></label>

                </a>
                </li>
                <li>
            <a>
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK). 'media/measurement_images/collar/pinned.png'; ?>" alt="sample" />

                <input type="radio" name="collar" id='pinned' value="PINNED" > 

                <label for="pinned"> <span>PINNED</span></label>

                </a>
                </li>
            <li class="border"></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="custom-s-buton">
                <input type="button" class="button custom-s" name="next" value="next">  
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="tab2" class="tab-content hide">
            <div id="cufftab2">
            <ul class="style-ul">
            <li>
            <a>
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK). 'media/measurement_images/cuff/round.png'; ?>"  alt="sample" />
                <input type="radio" name="cuff" id='round' value="Round" > 

                 <label for="round"> <span>ROUND</span></label>

                </a>
                </li>
                <li>
            <a>
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK). 'media/measurement_images/cuff/angled.png'; ?>" alt="sample" />
                <input type="radio" name="cuff" id='angled' value="ANGLED" > 

                <label for="angled"> <span>ANGLED</span> </label>

                </a>
                </li>
                <li>
            <a>
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK). 'media/measurement_images/cuff/two-button-angeld.png'; ?>" alt="sample" />
                <input type="radio" name="cuff" id='t-button' value="TWO BUTTON ANGLED" >

                <label for="t-button"> <span>TWO BUTTON ANGLED</span> </label>

                </a>
                </li>
                 <li class="border"></li>
                <li>
            <a>
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK). 'media/measurement_images/cuff/french-cuff.png'; ?>"  alt="sample" />
                <input type="radio" name="cuff" id='french-c' value="FRENCH CUFFS BARREL" > 

                <label for="french-c"> <span>FRENCH CUFFS BARREL</span> </label>

                </a>
                </li>
                <li>
            <a>
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK). 'media/measurement_images/cuff/french-angeld.png'; ?>"  alt="sample" />
                <input type="radio" name="cuff" id='french-a' value="FRENCH CUFFS ANGLED" > 

               <label for="french-a">  <span>FRENCH CUFFS ANGLED</span> </label>

                </a>
                </li>
                 <li class="border"></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="custom-s-buton">
                <input type="button" class="button btn-cart" name="next" value="next">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('input:radio').click(function() {
    jQuery('li:has(input:radio:checked)').addClass('active');
    jQuery('li:has(input:radio:not(:checked))').removeClass('active');
    });

jQuery('#collartab1 input').on('change', function() {
   alert(jQuery('input[name=collar]:checked', '#collartab1').val()); 
   //jQuery('.first').html($('input[name=collar]:checked', '#collartab1').val());



});


jQuery('#cufftab2 input').on('change', function() {
   alert(jQuery('input[name=cuff]:checked', '#cufftab2').val()); 
   // $('.prince').html($('input[name=cuff]:checked', '#cufftab2').val());

});

</script>
```

Please see the code and tell me why it is selected only one radio button
Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kb5ukdLd/ try this fiddle if correct

Comment: jQuery('li:has(input:radio:not(:checked))').removeClass('active'); here is the issue why you are removing active from all the radio buttons. Change the code it will start work. try to remove checked for particualr tabs or particualr group

Comment: I am removing because when i select one tab then that one will be active another will remove and their content will shown

Comment: have you tried the fiddle isnt that what you wanted?

Comment: yes when i tried in fiddle it is working fine but the same code when i used in the page then it will not work properly

Comment: if you want to select two from only one group i suggest you use checkbox. radio button allows only one selection per group

Comment: ya i got this.............this is the code where it shows problem
$(".style-ul li label").each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(){
   $(".style-ul li label").removeClass("checked");
   $(this).addClass("checked");
   }); 
  });

Comment: How to solve this problem if i am removing the code then selected portion also removed as image is called in .style-ul li label.checked span class

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons with the same name form a group from which one can only select one option at a time. What you possibly need is to convert those radio buttons into checkboxes and you will be able to select several of them.
You should put brackets after the name of the checkbox, like this:'collar[]', so the values selected will be set to the post values as an array with only the values of the selected ones.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="collar[]" value="SEMI SPREAD">
<input type="checkbox" name="collar[]" value="SPREAD">
<input type="checkbox" name="collar[]" value="BUTTON DOWN">
<input type="checkbox" name="collar[]" value="PINNED">
```

Then if you select the SPREAD and PINNED the post variable will looke like this:

```
array(...) {
  ["collar"]=>
   array(3) {
    [0]=>
      string(6) "SPREAD"
    [1]=>
      string(6) "PINNED"
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: But you can see name is different. There are two sections and two different names are there for two sectons and i want to select one radio button in each section but it is not working please go through my code

Comment: if you want to select two from only one group i suggest you use checkbox. radio button allows only one selection per group

Comment: I want to select only one in one group but the problem is when i select one in one group then when i select another in another group then first selected is removed why is it so?